# Combine two formulas in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to organize forms by due date (90 days from previous completion) using =(D7+90)and establish which forms are missing. When an error occurs instead of #VALUE! having it show NONE with =IFERROR (D7+90, "NONE")

Both work separately but I can't get the formulas to work together. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! What two formulas are you trying to get to work together? And what do you mean by "work together"?

Comment: =IFERROR(A+B, "NONE") and =(A+90) I'm trying to combine them so I can have a value equal either 90 days in the future or equal NONE.

Comment: Not able to replicate your issue. Formula works fine for me. You may want to share some sample data so that we can see the values, and also the desired output or scenario when the output should be "none".

Comment: Not sure what the issue was, but I redid it and it's now working

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data along with the formula you are trying so far,,, we try to fix it !!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was based on glitch or typo and was resolved without help. The question is not useful to general audience.